# Retrieving (relating) two separate tags/attributes using a single XPath query?

Tags: php, xpath, xml-parsing, domdocument

I am Xpathing a DOMDocument file I have. the general pattern of this domdocument is as follows:

```
<h2> Title info </h2>
<div> .... </div>
<p> ...</p>
<div class = format_text> 
  <p> 
    <a href= "http://link..."><img src = "http://sourceofimageOnline.com"></a>
  </p>
</div>
<h2> 2nd title</h2>
<div> .... </div>
<p> ...</p>
<div class = format_text> 
  <p> 
    <a href= "http://link..."><img src = "http://sourceofimageOnline.com"></img></a> 
    <a href = "http://linkanother.."><img src = "http://sourceofimageonline.com"</img></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

The key is to return the titles and the src attribute for images that are hyperlinks.
Essentially, I render it as :

Title 1 
  Img URI 1
Title 2
   Img URI 2
   Img URI 3
...
..

Now the Titles can be easily retrieved using

```
DomDocument->getElementsByTagNames('h2')
```

And the img src are retrieved by an XPATH query:

```
//div[@class = "format_text"]/p/a/img/@src
```

This returns all the information I need. However, I am being challenged by trying to get the img src's relate to the titles they fall under. Since they are retrieved independently, I am unable to comprehend what kind of Xpath query I need to execute to retrieve both such that the above constraint is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. fetch an array with XPath expression `/html/body//h2`
2. iterate over this array with another XPath expression
3. refer to the current `h2` with `.` and refer to the first link with

   `./../div[@class='format_text']/p/a[$counter]/img`

XPath expression where `$counter` is the array id.

Comment: thanks for the edit and the solution. I improvised mine, since I naturally did not put the entire HTML file as it was in this page, to be more specific to this solution, my XPath query is:
'//h2 | //div[@class = "format_text"]/p/a/img/@src' ... i got the piping idea from you, Best!

Comment: Please add `backticks` to the snippet above

Comment: ADDING TO THE QUESTION: THe above piping query retrieves all H2 tags irrespective of those that have subsequent images to them, how can I avoid the h2 tags that aren't meant to be there ?

Comment: Click on help on the right side of the text box, the part with `code`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12128/discussion-between-user1020069-and-sputnick)